# Allow more scroll (slack) before firing actual scroll further event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a box which has an overflow scroll on it. When you reach the end of the box; I want to fire an event (scroll to the next section of the page).

Below code works, however, I want some "slack" in it. So it does not needs to fire directly when you reach the end of your box, but only when you persist on scrolling downwards.

Any help on improving below code to reach this effect?

```
function whiteboxscroll (){
  $('.white-box-inner').on("DOMContentLoaded scroll",function(){
    var myDiv = $('.white-box-inner');
    myDiv.each(function(){
      el = this;
      if(isElementInViewport(el) === true) { // current white box is in view
        if (this.offsetHeight + this.scrollTop >= this.scrollHeight ) { //current box is at end of scroll
          //define the current section 'this' belongs to
          var current_section = $(this).parents().eq(1);
          // define the next section
          var next_section = $(current_section).next('.cd-section');
          // smoothscroll to this next section
          if(next_section.attr('id') !== undefined){ // only perform scroll if next section is defined
            smoothScroll($('#' + next_section.attr('id')));
          }
        }
        else if(this.scrollTop === 0){ // current box is at top of scroll
          //define the current section 'this' belongs to
          var current_section = $(this).parents().eq(1);
          // define the prev section
          var prev_section = $(current_section).prev('.cd-section');
          // smoothscroll to this next section
          if(prev_section.attr('id') !== undefined) { // only perform scroll if prev section is defined
            smoothScroll($('#' + prev_section.attr('id')));
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I tried to add a buffer of 50 pixels ie, but then the events never fires, since we will never reach that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to true when you reach the end of scrolling and check if that variable is true on mousewheel.

```js
var enable_scroll = false;

$(".container").scroll(function(e){
    $('p.info').html(this.scrollTop);
    if(this.offsetHeight + this.scrollTop >= this.scrollHeight ) {
        $('p.info').html("End of scroll. Flag enabled.");
        enable_scroll = true;
    }
    
})
.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e){ //DOMMouseScroll for FF
   if(enable_scroll){
      $('p.info').html("<strong>Event fired</strong>");
   }
});
```

```css
.container { height: 250px; overflow:auto;}
.inner {height: 1000px;}
p.info{ padding: 10px; color: #fff; background: orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <p class="info">Start scrolling</p>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">Scroll down</div>
</div>
<p class="bottom"></p>
```

Comment: This is actually not what I meant. I tried to set a treshold were you could make a "bounce back event" but that one was really buggy.